# How to show that the sequence is not monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^{30}}{2^n}$.

I want to check if the sequence is monotonic or strictly monotonic. If it is not monotonic, I want to check if it is monotonic from an index and on. Also if it is bounded.

I have thought to consider that the sequence is increasing.

Then

$$a_{n+1} \geq a_n \Rightarrow \frac{(n+1)^{30}}{2^{n+1}} \geq \frac{n^{30}}{2^n} \Rightarrow 2^n (n+1)^{30} \geq n^{30} 2^{n+1} \Rightarrow (n+1)^{30} \geq 2n^{30} \Rightarrow \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{30} \geq 2 \Rightarrow \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{30} \geq 2$$

Can we find from this a restriction for $n$ and then conclude that the sequence is not increasing? And after that the same to show that $a_n$ is not decreasing?

Is there also an other way to show that the sequence is not monotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_2>a_1$, the sequence is not decreasing. And since $a_1=\frac12$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, the sequence is not increasing.

Comment: I see! If we consider the sequence $b_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}$, this is not decreasing because of the limit when $n=0$ or do we consider that $n>0$ and so the sequence is monotonic?

Comment: That sequence is strictly decreasing if it starts when $n=1$. If it starts when $n=0$, then it is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: How can this be shown?

Comment: If $n\geqslant1$, then$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{-n^2-n+1}{\left(n^2+1\right) \left(n^2+2 n+2\right)}<0.$$

Comment: Great! And something about a last sequence... If we have the sequence $c_n=\frac{8^n}{n!}$ the same criterion cannot be applied, since $$\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n=\frac{8^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\frac{8^n}{n!}=\frac{8^n}{n!} \left( \frac{8}{n+1}-1\right)=\frac{7-n}{n+1}$$

But from that we do not conclude that $\mu_n$ is not monotonic, since it positive for some $n$ and negative for others, do we?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: How else could we conclude if it is monotonic or not?

Comment: That's already quite far from the original question isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=\frac{x^{30}}{2^x}$ on the interval $[1,+\infty)$

$$f'(x)=\frac{30x^{29}2^x-x^{30}2^x\ln{2}}{4^x}$$

For $x>\frac{30}{\ln{2}}$ we have that $f'(x)<0$ so $f$ is decreasing on $(\frac{30}{\ln{2}},+\infty)$ and increasing on $[1,\frac{30}{\ln{2}}]$

Thus the sequence is strictly decreasing for every $n \geq [\frac{30}{\ln{2}}]+1$

So the sequence is not monotonic in general but we can say that it is ''eventually'' monotonic